# Can't catch events with ActiveMQ listener on Pytest

Tags: python, activemq-classic, pytest

I'm trying to write a test case to see if my action is being transmitted into ActiveMQ topic. 
I check my code outside of pytest, somehow code runs smoothly and I can see my message generated an event on ActiveMQ topic. But If I run it inside pytest case, I can't catch the events. I can't seem to find a reason. We are setting the receiver but we don't get header list if we use pytest. Outside pytest works fine.

Version without pytest:

```
import messenger
import client
import time
import amq_client as aq

lst=aq.MyListener(aq.conn)
aq.conn.set_listener('', lst)
aq.conn.start()
aq.conn.connect(login=aq.user, passcode=aq.password)
aq.conn.subscribe(destination=aq.destination, ack='auto', id=1234)
print("Waiting for messages...")

resp=messenger.Messenger().send_message()
print(resp)
lognum=resp[1].split("=")[1]
time.sleep(10)

actions = [x['ENTITY_ACTION'] for x in lst.header_list]
accounts = [x['ACCOUNT'] for x in lst.header_list]

print('actions ', actions)
print('    ')
print('    ')
print('    ')
print('    ')
print('ACCOUNTS', accounts)


if(str(lognum) in accounts and 'NEW_ACCOUNT' in actions ):
    print('By this it WORKS')
```

Output:

```
actions ['NEW_ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT_GROUP_CHANGED']




ACCOUNTS ['720308353', '720308353']
By this it WORKS
```

Pytest version:

```
import pytest
import messenger
import amq_client as aq
import time

class Test_AmqTestCase(object):

    def test_newaccount(self):
        lst=aq.MyListener(aq.conn)
        aq.conn.set_listener('', lst)
        aq.conn.start()
        aq.conn.connect(login=aq.user, passcode=aq.password)
        aq.conn.subscribe(destination=aq.destination, ack='auto', id=1234)
        print("Waiting for messages...")

        resp=messenger.Messenger().send_message()
        print(resp)
        lognum=resp[1].split("=")[1]

        t_end=time.time()+30
        t_start=time.time()
        while time.time() < t_end:
            time.sleep(1)
            t_total=time.time()-t_start

        print('Total time for event occur :', t_total)
        print('    ')

        actions = [x['ENTITY_ACTION'] for x in lst.header_list]
        accounts = [x['ACCOUNT'] for x in lst.header_list]

        print('ACCOUNTS', accounts)
        assert (str(lognum) in accounts and 'NEW_ACCOUNT' in actions)
```

pytest result:

```
assert (str(lognum) in accounts and 'NEW_ACCOUNT' in actions)
E       AssertionError: assert ('720308351' in [])
E        +  where '720308351' = str('720308351')

Test_AmqCase.py:33: AssertionError
---------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
Waiting for messages...
['OK', 'LOGIN=720308351', 'end', '']
Total time for event occur : 30.017589569091797

ACCOUNTS []
```

Comment: Did you try the Pytest version on a fresh topic? If not, can you try and check if you get the same issue?

Comment: On fresh topic, pytest doesn't read as well. I can't get header or message body if I run it inside pytest.